# Getting Wifi to work on Ubuntu 12.10 for MacBookPro

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, mac

So I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my MacBookPro and I've tried installing various drivers such as Broadcom STA wireless, however when I install them or at least I think I've installed them, they do not show up in my additional drivers. Any solutions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

With some old versions of ubuntu on my laptops (PCs) after installing I usually pluged the Ethernet Cable because the Wireless adapter won't work, after updating the OS using the Ethernet connection the problem usually fixes.